# How to change Jquery animate duration during transition?

Tags: jquery

How i can change the duration of jquery animate method such that.. the animation starts slowly, then speeds up and then again slowly and ending?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can include `jQueryUI`, which has various easing options for animations.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing

---

For example:

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/f77BA/

```
$('div').animate(
    {'height':400},
    {easing:'easeInOutCubic',duration:2000});​
```

I should note that you don't need the entire jQueryUI download. Their [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download) lets you customize the download, so I'm pretty sure you could just include the Core to get the easing effects.

Comment: @Anish: Added a jsFiddle demo, but the jQueryUI link has demos of all the easing types. Just click each box for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easing plugin for jQuery: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

It's got like 30 different easing types.

You can also use several together like this:

```
$('#my-ele').animate({ left : 100 }, 500, 'easeInExpo', function () {
    $(this).animate({ left : 500 }, 500, 'linear', function () {
        $(this).animate({ left : 600 }, 500, 'EaseOutExpo');
    });
});
```

This uses the callback function of the `.animate()` function to create a three part animation that eases in, then animates linearly, then eases out.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pPzhY/ (Another demo I made a while ago that looks pretty good: http://jsfiddle.net/b6L8M/22/)